# How to insert a comma in between a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I having a string and i need to insert a comma in between a given string. Please help me with some ideas

```
declare @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj'
select @a
```

I expect the output as `'a,s,d,f,g,h,j'`

Comment: Don't do that in SQL to begin with. SQL, the language, is very poor in string manipulation. Why do you want to do that in the first place? What are you trying to do and where did this string come from? Perhaps there are better ways to do whatever you want to do that don't involve string manipulation

Comment: A recursive cte?

Comment: The answers below might help you, but whatever you use it will slow your query down significant. Why not do this in the presentation layer where its supposed to be done

Comment: I imagine a lot of people have this exact problem. I do not agree with the suggestion to close, nor all the down votes. I would have hoped this was included in the string_split from sql server 2016

Answer (score 1):

This will work in sql server 2008

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max)='23'
DECLARE @b INT=len(@a)

WHILE @b>1
SELECT @a=stuff(@a,@b,0,','),@b-=1

SELECT @a
```

If you ever upgrade to sql server 2017, you can use this version, assuming the string is no longer than 2047 characters(2047 is the max number in spt_values with type=P, otherwise you can use a number table or something similar):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max)='abcd'

SELECT string_agg(substring(@a,number+1,1),',')
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number < len(@a)
and type='P'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Panagiotis Kanavos comment strongly. Below snippet will work for you.

```
Declare @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj',@OUTPUT VARCHAR(MAX)= ''

SELECT @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT+AA+',' FROM (
SELECT number ,SUBSTRING(@a, number, 1) AA
FROM master.DBO.spt_values WHERE TYPE = 'P'
AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@a)
)A
Order by number

SELECT SUBSTRING(@OUTPUT,1,LEN(@OUTPUT)-1)
```

I used `spt_values` which is undocumented by Microsoft, which is not preferred. You can try the same with Numbers table instead.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server isn't designed to do this, but here's a simple way to do this in a while loop;

```
    DECLARE @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj'
    DECLARE @i int = 1
    DECLARE @output varchar(30)

    WHILE (@i <= len(@a))
    BEGIN
        SET @output = ISNULL(@output,'') + ',' + SUBSTRING(@a, @i, 1)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    SET @output = STUFF(@output,1,1,'')

    SELECT @output
```

Output: a,s,d,f,g,h,j

It takes each separate character of input and inserts a comma before it. The `STUFF` function removes the very first comma in the string, you could do this with a `SUBSTRING` or `RIGHT` if you preferred.

This would work on any length string you pass in if you tweak the length of @a and @output

Comment: you can improve your answer slightly using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1044552/how-to-insert-a-comma-in-between-a-string) method (don't tell anyone)

Answer (score 0):

Consider carefully Panagiotis Kanavos's comment, but if you want to do this with T-SQL, one possible approach is using recursive CTE and `FOR XML` (supported from SQL Server 2008):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, 1, 1) AS Symbol, 1 AS Position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, Position + 1, 1), Position + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE Position < LEN(@a)
)
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT CONCAT(N',',  Symbol)
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY Position
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, N'') AS Result
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
Result
a,s,d,f,g,h,j
```

Notes:
Just for information, starting with SQL Server 2017 you may use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, 1, 1) AS Symbol, 1 AS Position
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@a, Position + 1, 1), Position + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE Position < LEN(@a)
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Symbol, ',')
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## As has already been mentioned, this is a terrible idea.

## Do not do this in SQL Server if you can avoid it.

That said, if for some reason you can't avoid it, a set based solution to this would involve a numbers table.  If you don't have one of these you can generate one with little overhead using a `cte`.  To work with just one value you can do this:

```
declare @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj';

with t(t)as(select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))as t(t))
    ,n(n)as(select top(len(@a)) row_number()over(order by(select null)) from t,t t2,t t3,t t4)
select @a = stuff((select ',' + substring(@a,n,1)
                   from n
                   order by n
                   for xml path('')
                  )
                 ,1,1,''
                 );

select @a;
```

Which outputs: `a,s,d,f,g,h,j`

Or to apply this logic to a table of values you can do the following:

```
declare @t table (a varchar(100));
insert into @t values('asdfghj'),('qwerty'),('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm[];#?|');

with t(t)as(select t from(values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))as t(t))
    ,n(n)as(select top(select max(len(a)) from @t) row_number()over(order by(select null)) from t,t t2,t t3,t t4)
select stuff((select ',' + substring(a,n,1)
              from n
              where n.n <= len(t.a)
              order by n.n
              for xml path('')
             )
            ,1,1,''
            ) as CommaDelimited
from @t as t;
```

Which outputs:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              CommaDelimited                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a,s,d,f,g,h,j                                                             |
| q,w,e,r,t,y                                                               |
| q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m,[,],;,#,?,|           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works, i used the **STUFF()** function to insert the **,**

```
    declare @a varchar(15) = 'asdfghj'
    declare @totalchar int = len(@a)
    declare @counter int = @totalchar

    while @counter >=1
    begin 
            if @counter + 1 <= @totalchar
            begin
                 set @a = stuff(@a,@counter + 1, 0 , ',')
            end
            set @counter = @counter -1
    end

    select @a
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This easy method...

```sql
DECLARE @INPUT VARCHAR(10) = 'ABCD'
DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(50) = ''

WHILE @I < = LEN(@INPUT)
BEGIN
    SET @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + SUBSTRING(@INPUT,@i,1) + ','
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SET @OUTPUT = SUBSTRING(@OUTPUT,1,LEN(@OUTPUT) - 1)
PRINT @OUTPUT
```

Comment: It's usually considered bad form to copy somebody else's answer and re-post it with very minor changes.

Comment: Dear @Rich Benner.  This is my own code. I have not copied brother.